# KinveyError: A redirectUri is required and must be a string

Tags: nativescript, kinvey

Installed latest NativeScript Sidekick, started with "Enterprise Auth" template.
Followed documentation and am getting:

```
KinveyError: A redirectUri is required and must be a string
```

I have even tried to go to the Kinvey Console and enter something in the RedirectUri field but can't seem to resolve.

Comment: Did you add `redirectUri` key with value to the url to your kinvey config object.

Comment: I have this there:
https://auth.kinvey.com/